# My React app is not deploying properly on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel

The site is deployed but you can't add products to the cart and the cart itself is not accesible. It also starts with 2 products on it somehow.

Here is the repo with the link to vercel:

https://github.com/Alexx147896/Gardenia-React

No idea what's wrong, it works perfectly when i run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to figure out an error with just the link. But f.e. I'm seeing these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHYE8.png) in the console.

Somewhere in your code, are you trying to reduce an array that is set to null or isn't actually an array? I would think it's in your cart component and the error is triggered before rendering the component, since you see nothing when loading the cart page. When I navigate to https://gardenia-react.vercel.app/cart by url instead of clicking cart, I also get an ERROR 404 (not found). So there's probably some routing issues to fix in your project too. Also after the error happens, and you navigate back to /flowers. The page doesn't load, so it seems to, completely break the app.

Comment: Thank you for answering. All of that works fine when i run it locally. Navigating to the /cart route just shows an empty cart. Nothing really breaks the app so it's something Vercel is doing.

Comment: I've personally used Vercel too, and never had any issues. Perhaps it has something to do with versions? Perhaps your project is built on an older/newer version of certain dependencies than what Vercel supports? Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I managed to solve it. 

Basically i had this: 

const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || '[]';

When it should have been this:

const savedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];


Somehow it did work fine on localhost.